# WinUI 3.0 for desktop apps default project gives runtime error

Tags: c#, winui, winui-3

Using [Windows UI Library 3 Preview 2 (July 2020)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/) that was released just yesterday. On latest version of `VS2019 - Preview`, followed this official tutorial [Get started with WinUI 3 for desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/get-started-winui3-for-desktop) to create a desktop project. Project successfully compiles but gives the following error when running in debug mode. I'm using `Windows10 Pro ver. 1903`:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComWrappers.RegisterForTrackerSupport(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComWrappers)'.
  Source=WinRT.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at WinRT.ComWrappersSupport.set_ComWrappers(ComWrappers value)
   at WinRT.ComWrappersSupport.InitializeComWrappers(ComWrappers wrappers)
   at WinUI_DesptopPreview2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\DotNET5VS2019\Desktop_WinUI\WinUI_DesptopPreview2\WinUI_DesptopPreview2\obj\x64\Debug\net5.0\win-x64\App.g.i.cs:line 25
```

**Screenshot of the error**:

[image]

Comment: You have most likely found a bug in the preview, which is not uncommon mind you, also considering its only preview 2. If you are concerned about this there are channels where you can register this problem

Comment: @TheGeneral You are correct, it indeed is a bug (user `@user8961312` discovered it and found a solution, as well). Please see my comments below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well, updating .NET 5 SDK to preview 6 solved it for me.
Link to the installer:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.100-preview.6-windows-x64-installer

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow` and doing an excellent job even in your very first response. Keep up the good work. Your suggestion worked (thank you). Step 3 of their official document [Install WinUI 3 Preview 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/#install-winui-3-preview-2) is still asking for installing `.NET 5 SDK to preview 5` that (as you also encountered) does not work for `WinUI 3.0 - Preview 2`. Can't thank you enough for saving me lots of time.